# what should be added to the code not to get an error like "note: declared here WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI CreateProcessA"

Tags: c, windows, winapi, compiler-errors

Compiler: MingW gcc
System: Windows 10 x64
IDE: Visual studio code 1.55.1
Language: C

I am trying to call the `CreateProcessA()` function. If I don't add `WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI` in front of the function as the return type, the code doesn't compile.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void){

    LPCSTR lpApplicationName =  "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe";
    LPCSTR lpCommandLine = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes = NULL;
    BOOL bInheritHandles = TRUE;
    DWORD dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    LPVOID lpEnvironment = NULL;
    LPCSTR lpCurrentDirectory = NULL;
    LPSTARTUPINFOA lpStartupInfo;
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation;
    

    WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI CreateProcessA(
                    lpApplicationName,
                    lpCommandLine, 
                    lpProcessAttributes, 
                    lpThreadAttributes, 
                    bInheritHandles,
                    lpEnvironment,
                    lpCurrentDirectory,
                    lpStartupInfo,
                    lpProcessInformation);
    return 0;
}
```

Overall, I managed to compile the code only in this version, but I must admit that it looks quite ugly. I would like to assign the returned result to a variable, but each attempt results in a compiler error:

```
 gcc .\main.c -o main.exe
.\main.c: In function 'main':
.\main.c:30:5: warning: 'stdcall' attribute only applies to function types [-Wattributes]
     WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI ret;
     ^~~~~~~~~~
.\main.c:34:21: warning: passing argument 2 of 'CreateProcessA' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
                     lpCommandLine,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1450:11: note: expected 'LPSTR' {aka 'char *'} but argument is of type 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char *'}   
 ( LPCSTR, LPSTR, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, BOOL, DWORD,
           ^~~~~
.\main.c:38:21: warning: passing argument 6 of 'CreateProcessA' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]      
                     lpEnvironment,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1450:70: note: expected 'DWORD' {aka 'long unsigned int'} but argument is of type 'LPVOID' {aka 'void  
'}
 ( LPCSTR, LPSTR, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, BOOL, DWORD,
                                                                      ^~~~~
.\main.c:39:21: warning: passing argument 7 of 'CreateProcessA' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
                     lpCurrentDirectory,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1451:3: note: expected 'PVOID' {aka 'void *'} but argument is of type 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char *'}    
   PVOID, LPCSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOA, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION
   ^~~~~
.\main.c:40:21: warning: passing argument 8 of 'CreateProcessA' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]     
                     lpStartupInfo,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1451:10: note: expected 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char *'} but argument is of type 'LPSTARTUPINFOA' {aka 'struct _STARTUPINFOA *'}
   PVOID, LPCSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOA, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION
          ^~~~~~
.\main.c:41:21: warning: passing argument 9 of 'CreateProcessA' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]     
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1451:18: note: expected 'LPSTARTUPINFOA' {aka 'struct _STARTUPINFOA *'} but argument is of type 'LPPROCESS_INFORMATION' {aka 'struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION *'}
   PVOID, LPCSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOA, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.\main.c:32:11: error: too few arguments to function 'CreateProcessA'
     ret = CreateProcessA(
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1449:24: note: declared here
 WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI CreateProcessA
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PS C:\Users\tablet\Documents\c\WinApi32> gcc .\main.c -o main.exe
.\main.c: In function 'main':
.\main.c:34:21: warning: passing argument 2 of 'CreateProcessA' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
                     lpCommandLine,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1450:11: note: expected 'LPSTR' {aka 'char *'} but argument is of type 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char *'}   
 ( LPCSTR, LPSTR, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, BOOL, DWORD,
           ^~~~~
.\main.c:38:21: warning: passing argument 6 of 'CreateProcessA' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]      
                     lpEnvironment,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1450:70: note: expected 'DWORD' {aka 'long unsigned int'} but argument is of type 'LPVOID' {aka 'void  
'}
 ( LPCSTR, LPSTR, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, BOOL, DWORD,
                                                                      ^~~~~
.\main.c:39:21: warning: passing argument 7 of 'CreateProcessA' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
                     lpCurrentDirectory,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1451:3: note: expected 'PVOID' {aka 'void *'} but argument is of type 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char *'}    
   PVOID, LPCSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOA, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION
   ^~~~~
.\main.c:40:21: warning: passing argument 8 of 'CreateProcessA' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]     
                     lpStartupInfo,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1451:10: note: expected 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char *'} but argument is of type 'LPSTARTUPINFOA' {aka 'struct _STARTUPINFOA *'}
   PVOID, LPCSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOA, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION
          ^~~~~~
.\main.c:41:21: warning: passing argument 9 of 'CreateProcessA' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]     
                     lpProcessInformation);
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1451:18: note: expected 'LPSTARTUPINFOA' {aka 'struct _STARTUPINFOA *'} but argument is of type 'LPPROCESS_INFORMATION' {aka 'struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION *'}
   PVOID, LPCSTR, LPSTARTUPINFOA, LPPROCESS_INFORMATION
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.\main.c:32:5: error: too few arguments to function 'CreateProcessA'
     CreateProcessA(
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:44,
                 from .\main.c:2:
c:\mingw\include\winbase.h:1449:24: note: declared here
 WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI CreateProcessA
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Those are two different languages.

Comment: I'm using C, sorry I wrote quite fast

Comment: _"...the code doesn't compile..."_ - What's the exact error do you get - can't suggest a fix unless we know the problem.

Comment: That's not an error. It's a note by the compiler in an attempt to help you resolve the error above it.

Comment: I put an error code

Comment: you put declaration inside function

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to declare this type explicitly. Is there any clever way to write it down without making a declaration?

Comment: @Marcin.R is it already declared in `windows.h` for you. Your code is trying to *re-declare* it, not *call* it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to *re-declare* `CreateProcessA()`, you are not *calling* it.  It is already *declared* by `windows.h` for you, so just *call* it normally like any other function, eg:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

    STARTUPINFOA StartupInfo = {sizeof(STARTUPINFOA), 0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation = {0};

    LPCSTR lpApplicationName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe";
    LPCSTR lpCommandLine = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes = NULL;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes = NULL;
    BOOL bInheritHandles = TRUE;
    DWORD dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
    LPVOID lpEnvironment = NULL;
    LPCSTR lpCurrentDirectory = NULL;
    LPSTARTUPINFOA lpStartupInfo = &StartupInfo;
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation = &ProcessInformation;    

    BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcessA(
                    lpApplicationName,
                    lpCommandLine, 
                    lpProcessAttributes, 
                    lpThreadAttributes, 
                    bInheritHandles,
                    dwCreationFlags,
                    lpEnvironment,
                    lpCurrentDirectory,
                    lpStartupInfo,
                    lpProcessInformation);
    if (bSuccess)
    {
        CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
        CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);
    }
    else
        printf("CreateProcessA failed, error %u\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

Which can be simplified by removing all of those unnecessary variables:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){

    STARTUPINFOA StartupInfo = {sizeof(STARTUPINFOA), 0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation = {0};
    
    BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcessA(
                    "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe",
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    TRUE,
                    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &StartupInfo,
                    &ProcessInformation);
    if (bSuccess)
    {
        CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hThread);
        CloseHandle(ProcessInformation.hProcess);
    }
    else
        printf("CreateProcessA failed, error %u\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me, I even copied it and nothing. I have the same error as in the post above. I'm afraid it might be related to my environment. After your editing the code works, sorry but I got completely stupid :(. The worst thing about winapi is that it has a lot of its own defined types, it makes it goofy.

Comment: Now is ok, but I don't understand what is the difference between NULL located directly in the function body and NULL defined as a variable

Comment: There is no difference, since all of the parameters are being passed in by value. You don't need to use variables when passing in literals. I mean, you can if you want to, but it will just pollute the code

Comment: Ok, I understood the error concerning the attempt to declare the function in the main function "main", this is another step forward, but I do not understand what happened after the variable declaration forms were changed. I have to go through this step by step

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I didn't initialize the "STARTUPINFO" structure correctly